# can i receive notifications on my phone when there is activity on mi yodeya

Tags: support, notifications, android-app, ios-app

Is there a way I can set up the Stack Exchange app (for Android or iOS) so that, when there is activity, I receive a notification?

Now I only receive one if someone answers or comments on my question or answer, or they "at" me. I want more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get an RSS notification app, such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.madhur.dashclockfeedlyextension), and then point it at Mi Yodeya RSS feeds you're interested in. You can find links to them at the bottom-right of most pages.

Examples:

- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds - New questions
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=shabbat&sort=newest - New [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) questions
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag/shabbat - Recently active [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) questions
- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/12760 - New activity on our big [Samoan question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday)

Comment: Oh, nice!  I've seen the RSS links but never made the connection to using them with a phone app.

Answer (score 1):

The Android and (I understand) iOS apps notify you for inbox events -- comment and chat pings, and new answers to your questions.  I'm not aware of a way to get it to produce other notifications, but you might want to ask on [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

I use a combination of the app and the mobile web site on my phone; I find the app very hard to navigate, and the mobile web site lets me see the list of active questions easily.  The mobile web site also shows me my inbox and rep changes, so in the end I use the app to get my phone to buzz at me when Stack Exchange wants to tell me something.  I'm presumably missing some important capabilities there. :-)

Comment: I use the SE app the same way. It's unfortunate that it's so user-unfriendly